# Playing youtube video in Android Kitkat

Tags: android, webview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have problem showing youtube video in android kitkat webview. Whenever I try play video it always crash with message “Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code”
And from the crashlytics the message is “Unable to resolve host “www.youtube.com“: No address associated with hostname”
This is happened only for Kitkat and below

I already set hardwareAccelerated to true and also SetWebChromeClient

For information I am using Xamarin forms and use custom renderer for webview. This is the code for custom renderer

```
      this.Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        this.Control.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
        this.Control.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
        this.Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;                 
    this.Control.Settings.SetRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.High);
        this.Control.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;                  
this.Control.Settings.SetPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.OnDemand);
        if(App.AndroidOSVersion>16)
        this.Control.Settings.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false;
        if (UI.AllowFullScreen)
        this.Control.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        this.Control.LoadDataWithBaseURL(null, UI.YoutubeSource, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: stack trace please

Comment: The stacktrace not showing anything. it just showing Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code” and never get catched by the exception

Comment: so you don't catch any exceptions?

Comment: Please try `this.Control.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient())` instead of using ChromeClient and please also try using `this.Control.LoadUrl` instead of `LoadDataWithBaseURL`.

Comment: @G.hakim Yes. Correct
  

ElvisXia Still the same. It will directly crash on got SIGSEGV error